# Recargar un div jquery sin actualizar la pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, div

Utilizo la siguiente función para recargar un `div`.

```
function explode(){
   $("#div").load(location.href + " #div");
}
```

Sin tener que actualizar la pagina entera, pero al hacerlo, una vez recargado, los `scripts` de `javascript` y `jquery` que utilizo con el `div` y otros interiores a el dejan de funcionar.

¿Hay alguna manera recargar el `div` completo con todas sus funcionalidades?

Comment: Hola, los eventos ligados a los elementos en $(document).ready( ); en general no van a ser escuchados dentro del nuevo div. Debes "rebobinar" los comportamientos para que sean escuchados así: 1. Enlazar comportamientos usando un método general al cargar ej: `$(document).ready( function(){ enlazarEventosDeseados(); });` 2. enlazas los eventos que necesitas normalmente en un método aparte para tenerlos disponibles en todo momento `function enlazarEventosDeseados(){ // aquí la magia }`3. luego de cargar el contenido del div volver a invocar 2.

Comment: Me ha resultado, muchas gracias!!

Comment: @quevedo deberías poner eso como respuesta. Al menos te llevarás mi +1

Comment: @Tester Me alegra que te sirviera lo que indica quevedo como solución. Cuando escriba la respuesta, por favor acéptala como la correcta. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro. Muchas gracias por la ofreta. Creo que en lugar de una respuesta local, me voy a tomar un tiempo, para preparar un juego pregunta-respuesta que generalice el problema de modo que pueda ser más útil. Y, cuando lo haya publicado dejo un enlace aquí.